# Немогу понять почему сокет "держит" таймер?

Tags: linux, c, сокет, can

Столкнулся с проблемой, "не отрабатывает" алгоритм, так как я это задумал.

По моей логике: Требуется считывать "пришедшие" сообщения в течение 1000ms, после чего двигаться дальше.

Но на практике почему-то он **не выходит** из цикла почему именно так происходит, я так и не разобрался ???

```
        system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 10000 ");
        printf("ip link set %s type can bitrate %d \n", "can0", 10000);
        system("ip link set can0 up");

        // Good initialization messages road (socket)
        struct sockaddr_can addr;
        struct ifreq ifr;

        const char *ifname = "can0";

        if ((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0){
            perror("Error while opening socket");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
        ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

        addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
        addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
        //    printf("%s at index %d\n", ifname, ifr.ifr_ifindex);
        if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){
            perror("Error in socket bind");
            return 1;
        }
        // --- end initialization


        //тут запускаем таймер !
        int msec = 0, trigger = 1000; /* 1000ms */
        clock_t before = clock();

        do {
                // тут принимаем сообщения
                int numBytes = read(s, &frame, CAN_MTU);
                switch (numBytes)
                {
                printf("!! while(1) \n");
                case CAN_MTU:
                    if (processFrame(frame) == true)
                        speed_t = 10000;
                    break;
                case CANFD_MTU:
                    //  создай функцию для считывания КАН ФД сообщений
                    break;
                case -1:
                    //  проверяем значение сигнала и прерывание
                    if (EINTR == errno)
                        break;
                    //  маленькое тороможение
                    perror("not read");
                    usleep(100);
                default:
                    break;
                }

          clock_t difference = clock() - before;
          msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
         } while ( msec < trigger );

        // останавливаем поток
        system("ip link set can0 down");


        // останавливаем таймер !
        if(speed_t > 0)
            speed == true;
        if(speed_t == 0)
            teh_per_1++;
```

В общем вечно переходит в функцию `processFrame` и так выводит принятые сообщения.

```
 bool processFrame(struct can_frame frame)
{
    printf("processFrame tyt \n");
    int len = 0;
    unsigned char data[8];

    printf("CAN ID : 0x%02x \n", frame.can_id); // %X вывод  в 16-дцатеричке %d в 10-ричке.
    printf("frame.can_id : 0x%02x \n", frame.can_id );
    printf("len = : 0x%02x \n", frame.can_dlc); len = frame.can_dlc ;
    printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", frame.data[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = frame.data[i];
    printf("data : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);
    printf("\n ---------------- \n");

    return true;
}
```

**В общем так и не понял, почему `socket` отрубает таймер.**

---

В общем вот вывод по которому видно что программа не выходит из процесса read:

```
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/novosibirsk# ls
TextFile.txt  main.c  main.h
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/novosibirsk# gcc main.c -o tream
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/novosibirsk# ls
TextFile.txt  main.c  main.h  tream
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/novosibirsk# ./tream
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 10000
processFrame tyt
CAN ID : 0x333
frame.can_id : 0x333
len = : 0x08
DATA :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
data :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
 ----------------
processFrame tyt
CAN ID : 0x333
frame.can_id : 0x333
len = : 0x08
DATA :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
data :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
 ----------------
processFrame tyt
CAN ID : 0x333
frame.can_id : 0x333
len = : 0x08
DATA :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
data :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
 ----------------
processFrame tyt
CAN ID : 0x333
frame.can_id : 0x333
len = : 0x08
DATA :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
data :  [33]  [17]  [13]  [21]  [0]  [212]  [33]  [1]
 ----------------
```

Comment: Вы ожидали, что вызов `clock()` запустит какой-то таймер? И что должно с ним происходить дальше? / Вероятно вам нужно воспользоваться чем-то из `alarm()`, `setitimer()` или `timer_create()`

Comment: @avp Да,  он отчитает 1000 мс если за это время пришло одно сообщение то у меня выбирается "скорость" и код действует дальше в соответствии с алгоритмом.

Comment: Похоже, вы не поняли. Функция [clock()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) всего лишь возвращает текущее время, прошедшее от запуска процесса в условных микросекундах

Comment: Для отладки просто печатайте `clock()` в конце цикла, неужели он не растет монотонно?

Comment: @avp увы он до туда не доходит, он считывает `read`(циклом "все сообщения" ) но дальше почему-то не идет

Comment: Т.е. у вас **первый же** `read()` **не завершается**? (и соответственно `switch` не выполняется)

Comment: @avp он же заходит в функцию `processFrame(struct can_frame frame)`. А вот то что он не выходит из функции , это да проблема (при этом независимо , есть ли сообщения либо их нету "просто тупо сидит их ждет").

Comment: OK. Давайте по шагам. Раз управление попадает внутрь `processFrame()`, значит вы должны видеть печать в ней. Приведите ее в обновлении ответа. Кстати, Вы уверены, что функция не выполняет return? Строку `"\n ---------------- \n"` она печатает?

Comment: @avp да, обновил вопрос строку печатает :3 просто не понятно почему дальше "не идёт"

Comment: Значит больше читать пока нечего. Это уже вам лучше знать протокол, который вы читаете сокетом. Чтобы не ждать бесконечно долго можно перед read вызывать [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) с таймаутом.